# How do I setup a pytest fixture with a dynamic scope?

Tags: python, scope, pytest

I am reading through the pytest fixture docs and I cam across dynamic scope.

**Scope** determines how long your fixture will be active/when it will be destroyed and recreated.

Usually you have to hardcode your scope via e.g.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
 def smtp_connection():
     return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)
```

In this case the SMTP instance is kept until the last test in the module ran.

[According to the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#dynamic-scope) you can also add dynamic scopes like this:

```py
def determine_scope(fixture_name, config):
    if config.getoption("--keep-containers", None):
        return "session"
    return "function"


@pytest.fixture(scope=determine_scope)
def docker_container():
    yield spawn_container()
```

Now the scope is `session` if you pass a parameter, else its `function`.

**Question:** What is `config`? Where do I pass the parameter `--keep-containers`? I am not allowed to do `pytest --keep-containers path/to/test.py`. Is `config` just a random object here?

Answer (score 0):

Config is not a random parameter, it's an instance of [_pytest.config.Config](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/_modules/_pytest/config.html). You can pass it a parameter from console using `pytest_addoption` in `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--keep-containers', action='store', default='True')


def determine_scope(fixture_name, config):
    if ast.literal_eval(config.getoption("--keep-containers", None)):
        return "session"
    return "function"
```

And run it using `pytest --keep-containers=True path/to/test.py`